# Switching over to next Screen from the main Activity by clicking on the Button

Tags: android, switching, buttonclick

I am working on an application where I need to go to the next Screen form the Main Actvity when I Click on the Image Button of the Main Activity Screen.

I had searched a bit on Net regarding this and found something like the OnClickListener method. I am still stuck for what exactly I want to do actually.

Can anyone please tell me how to do the same.

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(){    
    public void onCLick(View v){
      Intent i=new Intent(
             YouCurrentClass.this,
             NameOfJaveInWhichYouWantToMove.class);
      startActivity(i);
    }
};
```

Comment: As I understood the question it seems more like he wants to change views not start an new activity, but otherwise its also a good solution

Comment: Sorry for the being confusing, actually I want to just switch over to a Whole New VIEW when I click on the button form the main activity.

Comment: Then use the reply send by:  user440336 ,

Answer (score 1):

if you have your view as xml layout in your project then what you want to do is

onTouch or onClick or whatever triggers your change view

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoutYouWantToDisplay);
```

Comment: Be careful that this version does not trigger onCreate() method for the Activity that you switch to, so this can cause some problems. The 'Intent' version triggers the life-cycle for Activity.

Answer (score 0):

or other method of loading all pages at start and after the application simply just manage the visibility layouts.
Try to research the ViewFlipper is interresting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...it will help you for sure

```
public class your_file_name extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public ImageButton any_name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    any_name = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.given id<check in your layout for it> );
any_name. setOnClickListener(){    
public void onCLick(View v){
  Intent myintent=new Intent(your_file_name.this, next_desired_class.class);
  startActivityforresult(myintent,100);
}
};
```